PPP3 Textbook Suggest Apparently Non-Existent "expect" Function
So I am attempting to learn C++ after taking some Java a year back and a basic C++ course a few months ago by using Bjarne's Programming Principles and Practices, third edition, and I made it so far to the fourth chapter, where it delves into errors and how to handle them and prevent them.
The specific problem I have is that Bjarne talks about a function expect, but I cannot find any other sources mentioning this function.
Doing a simple google search for "site:cppreference.com expect" leads to expected, which appears to have an entirely different syntax.
For example, I have the code assembled from the textbook, snippets here:
// try to find a pair of values such that the precondition holds but the postcondition doesn't

import std;
using namespace std;

// calculate area of the rectangle
int area(int length, int width) {
    // if the arguments are positive
    expect([&] {return 0 < length && 0 < width; }, "bad arguments for area()"); // line of error
    int result = length * width;
    expect([&] {return 0 < result; }, "bad area() result"); /// line of error
    return result;
}


int main() {
    // simple test, infinite loop
    while (true) 
        try {
            int length = 0, width = 0;
            cout << "Enter a length and a width: "; cin >> length >> width;
            cout << "Area is: " << area(length, width) << endl;
        } catch (...) {
            cerr << "An error occured" << endl;
        }

    return 0;
}

However, when I attempt to compile this (mind you, using c++latest from Visual Studio 2022's compiler), I get the error:
trythis04.cpp
Z:\...\trythis04.cpp(9): error C3861: 'expect': identifier not found
Z:\...\trythis04.cpp(11): error C3861: 'expect': identifier not found

Bjarne suggests it is a function that is called as expect(functionToTest, stringToPrintInError). In the textbook he writes:

To deal with [being unable to see whether an if statement checks an invariant or is part of the ordinary logic of the function], we introduce a function called expect to do the checking. As arguments expect() takes a function to test and a string used to report errors.

Is this an error on his part? Did I do something incorrectly? Is this something that was later revised after the textbook was published? What is the correct function here instead, if this does not exactly exist?

I suspect it's a handwritten function that calls a callable which, if it returns false, throws an exception with the given string.  Also, we don't use "Yoda conditionals" anymore (they make code harder to read and compilers are now pretty good at warning about unintended assignment).

"Is this an error on his part?" Where, which error do you mean?

is this all the code? I remember Bjarne using some custom headers for the examples and exercises

I dont have the book at hand. I can imagine that the example code isnt actually meant to compile but rather to motivate introduction of that expect function. When he writes "we introduce a function called expect to do the checking." he is talking about a custom function. It is not something from std

From the paragraph you quoted, this seems to be in a section about design-by-contract. The C++ committee mailing has many proposals regarding language support for the idiom. It almost landed in C++20 (and pulled when issues were brought up). I suspect Bjarne wrote the section back when some form of it was still likely to land (but before the bike-shedding stage was finished).

@Den-Jason I disagree with the claim that we don't use Yoda conditions any more, especially when talking about checking if value fits in the range, as in 13 <= x && x <= 42. This improves readability (for humans, not for the compiler), in my opinion. We use this style at work, as it resembles the regular maths notation (13 ≤ x ≤ 42) more closely.

The missing function can be found in the support material for the book: https://www.stroustrup.com/PPP_support.h

@BoP yeah apparently I missed that part and Bjarne mentions it right after the "try this" that this was about. I'm kind of stuck coping without the support header/module since it won't compile with Visual Studio 2022's c++latest standard, it just spits out compiler errors at me.

@Den-Jason the "Yoda conditionals" depicted above are from the textbook. But why would they be discouraged? In some cases, it makes it far easier to read because it basically parallels normal mathematic conditionals, and code is all about putting our ideas into clear and concise instructions. I never understood why some of my professors wrote it as a < x && b > x when it's much more concise (and less logic-error-prone) to write out a < x && x < b.

@Xbox360 0 == some_number can be used as Yoda notation, because the common typo 0 = some_number will cause a compiler error (but some_number = 0 not necessarily). I havent heard 0 < x being called a "Yoda notation", it could be just a consistent use of < for the comparisons. Imho 0 < length is perfectly fine and readable, but of course readability is up to opinions

From the context of your code, expect is effectively an assert function. But instead of taking a boolean expression, it takes a std::function, which can be a lambda. The function passed is expected to return true if conditions are good and false when not.
Here's a simple version of expect that you can paste into your program right above the area function:
// optional includes you might need
//#include <functional>
//#include <iostream>
//#include <string>

void expect(const std::function<bool()>& fn, const std::string& s = "") {
    bool result = fn();
    if (!result) {
        std::cout << "ERROR: " << s << std::endl;
        throw std::exception(s.c_str());
    }
}

I just tried it out with your code and it works fine.  When I run your program:
Enter a length and a width: 4 5
Area is: 20
Enter a length and a width: -4 55
Area is: ERROR: bad arguments for area()
An error occured
Enter a length and a width:


"it takes a std::function", not necessarily, it could be any callable

Don't all "callables" cast to a std::function ?  Lambdas definitely do.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai - I'd encourage you post your own answer.  I might even take mine down and upvote yours.

std::invocable ?

the answer is fine. Its just a nitpick. I am picking on this because I often see the misunderstanding that std::function should always be used for callables among beginners.

template <std::predicate Fn> void expect(Fn fn, std::string_view s)

std::cout for error reporting? wouldn't you instead want to use std::cerr (assuming it's also part of the standard library) to report the error?

@Xbox360 in principle you are right, but I wouldnt want any output in there. You write to cerr in main when you catch the exception. In a small example it is "ok" though.
